# How do I use ejs templates/partials with webpack?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, ejs

I'm trying to create a full stack app using Express and ejs, and using webpack to bundle the client side assets.  When I set it up without ejs it all works perfectly.  The problem has come when I've tried to change the index.html to an index.ejs that uses partials for header, footer etc.  Ultimately this will be a multipage app which is why I'm using the ejs templates.

I've tried using ejs-loader (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-loader), ejs-compiled-loader (https://github.com/bazilio91/ejs-compiled-loader) and ejs-html-loader (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-html-loader) without any joy.

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm sure it's really straightforward but for the life of me I can't work out how to link up ejs to webpack and get the templates to work.

I've included the code that works with template.html below.  I need to know how to change that to use index.ejs?

My file structure looks like this:

- --dist (output from webpack)
- --src (containing index.ejs)
- ----partials (containing partials for index.ejs)
- app.js
- webpack.common.js
- webpack.dev.js
- webpack.prod.js
- package.json
  etc.

Index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <% include partials/head %> 
</head>
<body>
<main>
<% include partials/main %>
</main>
<% include partials/footer %>
</body>
</html>
```

And my config files look as follows (I've only included the two that merge to make the build congfig):

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require("path")

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/index.js",
    vendor: "./src/vendor.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
      use: ["html-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
            outputPath: "imgs"
          }
        }
      }      
    ]
  },
}
```

webpack.prod.js

```
const path = require("path")
const common = require("./webpack.common")
const merge = require("webpack-merge")
const {
  CleanWebpackPlugin
} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contentHash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
    new TerserPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/template.html",
      minify: {
        removeAttributeQuotes: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeComments: true,
      }
    })]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[contentHash].css",
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        "css-loader",
        "sass-loader"
      ]
    }]
  }
});
```

This is my first post, if I've not included anything crucial please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: I am true having issues with this. Everything else is being watched except .ejs partials. I can get index.ejs to be watched by adding entry: ["./src/index.js", "./src/index.ejs"], but not sure how to watch all the other ejs partials.

Answer (score 0):

In Webpack 5, I've used **EJS** templates by taking advantage of the `preprocessor` option of the `html-loader`.

For details of the `preprocessor` option see [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader#preprocessor).

A simple implementation for a multi-page app would be:

****1.** install packages:**

`npm i html-loader ejs html-webpack-plugin -D`

*! Note that using `html-loader` will disable the default loader used by `html-loader-plugin`.*

****2.**  Webpack config (`html-webpack-plugin`)** - define the pages, together with their specific parameters & title. Template path should be absolute.

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.ejs'), // absolute path
      filename: 'index.html',
      templateParameters: {
        bodyClass: 'page-index'
      },
      title: 'Index | Webpack Starter',
    }),
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/about.ejs'), // absolute path
      filename: 'about.html',
      templateParameters: {
        bodyClass: 'page-about'
      },
      title: 'About | Webpack Starter',
    }),
  ]
}
```

****3.**  Webpack config (`html-loader`)** - set-up `html-loader` with `preprocessor` option. Each partial should be added as a dependency to the Webpack compiler. Also, we can pass `htmlWebpackPlugin.options` as template parameters.

```js
const ejs = require('ejs');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
 // ...
 module: {
   rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ejs$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: {
          preprocessor: (content, loaderContext) => {
            try {
              const templatePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.ejs');

              // trigger re-compile if partial has changed
              // see: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/issues/386
              const partialsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './src/partials');
              fs.readdirSync(partialsPath).forEach((file) => {
                if (file.endsWith('.ejs')) {
                  const filePath = `${partialsPath}/${file}`;
                  loaderContext.addDependency(filePath);
                }
              });

              const templateParameters = {
                // ... add your data here
              };

              // OPTIONAL: expose htmlWebpackPlugin object in EJS templates
              const currentHtmlWebpackPlugin = loaderContext._compiler.options.plugins.filter(
                (plugin) =>
                  typeof plugin === 'object' &&
                  plugin.options &&
                  plugin.options.template &&
                  plugin.options.template === loaderContext.resourcePath,
              )[0];

              if (typeof currentHtmlWebpackPlugin === 'object') {
                Object.assign(templateParameters, {
                  htmlWebpackPlugin: currentHtmlWebpackPlugin,
                });

                if (typeof currentHtmlWebpackPlugin.options.templateParameters !== 'function') {
                  Object.assign(templateParameters, {
                    ...currentHtmlWebpackPlugin.options.templateParameters,
                  });
                }
              }

              return ejs.render(content, templateParameters, { filename: templatePath });
            } catch (error) {
              loaderContext.emitError(error);

              return content;
            }
          },
        },
      },

    // other rules
   ]
 }
}
```

****4.**  Webpack Dev Server** - set-up dev-server to watch `ejs` files for changes:

```js
devServer: {
    hot: true,
    watchFiles: ['./src/**/*.ejs'],
  },
```

Example project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-7dw627?file=webpack%2Fwebpack.config.common.js